# Replace a column of data with another column from another table

Tags: mysql, database

I would like to replace a column of data in a table.

TableA
Uid  - int
AnotherUid   - int

TableB
Uid  - int

TableA.uid = Table.B uid 
And I am trying to replace the TableB.Uid with TableA.AnotherUid

```
Select * from TableB a,  TableA b  where a.uid=b.uid 
update TableB set a.uid=b.AnotherUid
```

I got a SQL syntax error from MySQL at TableB set a.uid=b.AnotherUid.

Please kindly help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
UPDATE TableB T
   SET T.uid = 
     (SELECT AnotherUid 
     FROM TableA A
     WHERE A.uid = T.uid)
```

Comment: someone likes it? i was about to delete but guess ill leave it. im uncomfortable with it as it stands and i dont have the means to test right now.  alocus - plz let me know if you have any luck with it

Comment: I am trying it now and getting syntax error. Yet this query makes a lot more sense than mine.

Comment: this line  (SELECT A.AnotherUid  needs to be changed to (SELECT AnotherUid, then it works.  Thanks

Comment: ok, not what i wouldve expected but you tried it i didnt. glad it worked for you, ill edit in kind.

Comment: Glad that it is working for you however I would prefer much simpler (and probably more efficient because of no sub-select) syntax for this query as I posted.

Comment: I am receiving an Error calling something like 'Operation has to use an updated Query'. What is this about? (Help links me here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/office/jj681038%28v=office.15%29.aspx)

Answer (score 6):

```
UPDATE TableB SET TableB.Uid = (SELECT AnotherUid FROM TableA WHERE TableA.Uid = TableB.Uid)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this query:

```
Update TableB, TableA
Set TableB.uid = TableA.AnotherUid
Where TableB.uid = TableA.uid;
```

For MySQL manual on join in the Update query please refer: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html and see this example in their doc:

```
UPDATE items,month SET items.price=month.price
WHERE items.id=month.id;
```